# Adaptive Payments payment COMPLETED although actionType is CREATE

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Using the [Adaptive Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) I acquired a pay key using the API method [`Pay`](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI) with these parameters:

```
actionType:                      CREATE
receiverList.receiver(0).email:  ...
receiverList.receiver(0).amount: 5
currencyCode:                    EUR
cancelUrl:                       ...
returnUrl:                       ...
requestEnvelope.errorLanguage:   en_US
```

Then I started the embedded pay flow with this URL:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?expType=light&payKey=...

After the lightbox is closed again, when I call the [`PaymentDetails`](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPaymentDetails) method on the pay key, it gives me (among other values):

```
paymentInfoList.paymentInfo(0).transactionStatus: COMPLETED
status:                                           COMPLETED
actionType:                                       CREATE
```

So apparently the payment is already executed, though I did not call the [`ExecutePay`](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APExecutePaymentAPI) method yet.

The [docs](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPayAPI) state (under the topic "PayRequest Fields"):

> **actionType** *xs:string*
>
> *(Required)* Whether the Pay request pays the receiver or whether the
>   Pay request is set up to create a payment request, but not fulfill the
>   payment until the `ExecutePayment` is called.
>
> Allowable values are:
>   [...]
>   `CREATE` – Use this option to set up the payment instructions with `SetPaymentOptions` and then execute the payment at a later time with
>   the `ExecutePayment`.

What did I miss?

Comment: Did you figure this out or still waiting for an answer?

Comment: As you can see below, no answer yet. http://xkcd.com/979/? :)

Comment: I was hoping you might have figured it out and just not updated :D

Comment: I, too, am finding that specifying `actionType=CREATE` causes the payments to be made immediately after the buyer approves the payment on PayPal.

Answer (score 3):

We ended up just using the Preapproval API and calling Pay with that. In the response I got to my e-mail I was told:

```
"PayPal does not allow you to hold any amount of money in somebody else's PayPal account     and that is why we have Preapproval API."
```

I'm still not sure why Create appears to make the charge without requiring an ExecutePayment call, but for my workflow (which I hope is valuable to you), the Preapproval API is the way to go.

Comment: Afaik the Preapproval API does not support the "embedded payment flow" (sandbox instead of redirect) yet.

Comment: Completely overlooked that. Definitely useful to know. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: In that case why would they implement CREATE type? How can I call Execute if there is no need to do that?

Answer (score 3):

(I know it's been three years since this question was asked, but since another user referenced this question, I'll answer it anyway.)

In short, if you send the sender over to the PayPal website, and they approve the payment, the payment will complete immediately, regardless of what you set `actionType` to.

The purpose of setting `actionType=CREATE` is to give you a little bit of time to make additional API calls against the paykey before the payment completes.  It's primarily useful when you're doing implicit payments -- e.g., those payments where the sender and the API caller are the same party (and you've set `sender.useCredentials=true`, set your email address in `senderEmail`, or set your secure merchant account ID in `sender.accountId`), or those payments where you're using a preapproval that the sender has previously approved.  Since these types of payments would normally complete right away (if you set `actionType=PAY`), setting `actionType=CREATE` gives you a little bit of time to make other API calls against the payment (such as SetPaymentOptions) before the payment completes.

If you're doing an explicit payment (where the sender has to go to the PayPal website to approve the payment), however, you'd just make those additional calls before sending the user over to PayPal.