# Is it possible to use actionType CREATE when making a chained payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I currently use express checkout and I like that after the user approves the payment, it redirects back to my site where I can then execute the payment and update things on my end. Now I need to switch to Adaptive Payments because I want to use chained payments, but it seems like you can't use the CREATE actionType, only PAY which forces me to use IPN.

IPN is not as fast as I'd like, which is why I want to be able to do a flow similar to how I have it set up with express checkout.

Anyone have information about this? I see the CREATE payType in the api docs, but it doesn't seem to do anything from my testing.

Comment: Well I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155419/adaptive-payments-payment-completed-although-actiontype-is-create which makes it seem like this isn't possible. Bummer...

Comment: Have you tested it in the sandbox?  Seems like I've done it before, but it's been a while.  Also, IPN is instant, as the name implies.  Not sure how much quicker you're looking for than instant..??  It's recommended to use IPN even with Express Checkout so you can handle things like e-checks where the payment doesn't actually clear until later.

Comment: I know the name implies that it is instant, but seems like it can take a bit. Thanks for the comment, sir!