# PayPal Adaptive Payments: ExecutePayment returns payKey AP-XXXX has already been used to make a payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I first call the Pay API with actionType=CREATE
and only after user has been redirected to my returnUrl i'm calling the ExecutePayment API with the pay_key received at first Pay call.

PP returns this error message: payKey AP-XXXX has already been used to make a payment

Does anyone know what could trigger this error and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve this out?? I have same issue . Doco says that when making payment request with CREATE we have to cal ExecutePayment , but it seems it gets executed anyway. Not sure if only in sandbox.

Comment: this api is so confusing

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an explicit payment (redirecting the user to the PaPal website) and therefore the confirmation of the user leads to the execution of the payment. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473433/1536921